# Get form submission data from radio buttons generated by a 2d array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, submission

I created an HTML table containing radio fields using a multidimensional array.

How can I get the selected values from the form submission?

My current code:

```
$cakedata = array(
    array("shape" => "Heart",       "flavor" => "Chocolate",    "toppings" => "Cookies"),
    array("shape" => "Rectangle",   "flavor" =>  "Vanilla",     "toppings" =>  "Spun-sugar Flowers"),
    array("shape" => "Square",      "flavor" =>  "Lemon",       "toppings" => "Mini Chocolate Candies"),
    array("shape" => "Round",       "flavor" =>  "Cheesecake",  "toppings" => "Marshmallows")
);
echo "<form action = 'diycake.php' method = 'post'>";
echo "<table><table border = '1'>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> Cake Shape </th>";
    echo "<th> Cake Flavor </th>";
    echo "<th> Cake Toppings </th>";
$i = 0;
foreach($cakedata as $row => $innerArray){
    foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
        if($i==0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "<td><input type ='radio' name ='radio".$i."'>".$value."</td>";
        if($i==2){  
            echo "</tr>"; 
            $i=-1;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table><br>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>";
echo "</form>";
echo '<pre>'; print_r($cakedata); echo '</pre>';
```

How do I receive the user's selections?

Comment: On your `diycake.php` you should check, `isset($_POST['submit'])`, if the form was sent. The value from the radio button is also in the `$_POST[]` variable, accessible by it's name. So you could do a loop, and check if `isset($_POST['radio' . $i])`. If it's set, the value of the radio button is in this variable. You would probably also include the `value`-attribute in the radio-button tag, to get the actual value. Otherwise it will be empty for all buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DIY Cake</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>D-I-Y Cake</h1>
        <?php
        $cakedata = array(
                        array("shape" => "Heart",       "flavor" => "Chocolate",    "toppings" => "Cookies"),
                        array("shape" => "Rectangle",   "flavor" =>  "Vanilla",     "toppings" =>  "Spun-sugar Flowers"),
                        array("shape" => "Square",      "flavor" =>  "Lemon",       "toppings" => "Mini Chocolate Candies"),
                        array("shape" => "Round",       "flavor" =>  "Cheesecake",  "toppings" => "Marshmallows")
                );
        echo "<form action = 'diycake.php' method = 'post'>";
        echo "<table><table border = '1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th> Cake Shape </th>";
            echo "<th> Cake Flavor </th>";
            echo "<th> Cake Toppings </th>";
                $i = 0;
                foreach($cakedata as $row => $innerArray){
                    foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
                        if($i==0){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            }
                            echo "<td><input type ='radio' name ='radio".$i."' value='" . $value . "'>".$value."</td>";
                        if($i==2){  
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                            $i=-1;
                            }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table><br>";
        echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>";
        echo "</form>";

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

diycake.php

```php
<?php

// check, if form was sent
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $outerNumberArray = 4; // actually the outer number of your array
  for($i = 0; $i < $outerNumberArray; $i++) {
    if (isset($_POST['radio' . $i])) {
      echo "Your value from radio" . $i . ": " . $_POST['radio' . $i] . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio button `name` attributes are expected to be identical in their relative group.  This way the behavior of unchecking other radio buttons in the same "family" can be automated.  You shouldn't append a counter to the `name` values.

I recommend wrapping your cake attribute radio elements in `<label>` tags so that the text represents a clickable element to affect the radio button.

As a matter of best practice and improving code maintainability, create all of the table's content dynamically by referencing the columns and values in the `$cakedata` array.  If you ever want to add or remove cells from your table, you will only need to adjust your array -- not the HTML markup.  [Demo of `printf()`](https://3v4l.org/AaBTF)

If you ever need to adjust your HTML markup, that can be simplified by declaring template strings with placeholders -- this is, again, best practice because it affords making fewer changes.

Use `required` on a least one of the radio buttons in each group if you want to enforce client-side validation that each radio has a selection.  Client-side validation is never a replacement for server-side validation; it only improves the UX.

*[clears throat]* I must warn that modern web development trends indicate that some developers prefer to use a client-side language to populate HTML markup (not server-side languages, such as PHP).

<sub>(Neither of the below snippets were actually tested. Leave a comment if I've made any mistakes.)</sub>

```
$cakedata = [
    ["shape" => "Heart",     "flavor" => "Chocolate",  "toppings" => "Cookies"],
    ["shape" => "Rectangle", "flavor" => "Vanilla",    "toppings" => "Spun-sugar Flowers"],
    ["shape" => "Square",    "flavor" => "Lemon",      "toppings" => "Mini Chocolate Candies"],
    ["shape" => "Round",     "flavor" => "Cheesecake", "toppings" => "Marshmallows"]
];

$headings = array_keys($cakedata[0] ?? []);

$th = <<<TH
    <th>Cake %s</th>
TH;

$td = <<<'TD'
    <td><label><input type="radio" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" required>%2$s</label></td>
TD;

?>
<form action="diycake.php" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($headings as $name) {
                printf($th, htmlentities(ucwords($name)));
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($cakedata as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
                foreach ($row as $attr => $value) {
                    printf($td, htmlentities($attr), htmlentities($value));
                }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the `$_POST` payload will have `$_POST['submit']` with a value of `Submit`.  This should be your first validation check before doing any else (don't even bother connecting to the database if the form submission doesn't pass all validations).

The `$_POST` array will also be expected to contain `$_POST['shape']`, `$_POST['flavor']`, and `$_POST['toppings']`.  You can easily check that these exist with a single call of `isset()`, but you might as well check each with `!empty()` individually.  For that matter, you should also confirm that the submitted values also EXIST in `$cakedata`.  These heavy-handed validations are essential if you want to have a stable, secure application.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $valid = true;
    foreach (array_keys($cakedata[0] ?? []) as $column) {
        if (empty($_POST[$column]) || !in_array($_POST[$column], array_column($cakedata, $column))) {
            $valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // only proceed with server-side processes if the submission was completely valid.
}
```